# tweak of two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I am trying to merge two csv files based on 1st column (include both "exact string match" and "partial match") and if doesn't match - add those string but with blank 2nd column like

```
file1.csv
string1.str1.co.in,ZSER
string2.str2.com,ABCD
string3.str.co.in,ZSE
string4.str2.com,ACD
......

file2.csv
string1.str1.co.in, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com, 2nd, hello
string3, 3rd, helloz
string4, 4th, hellox
string5, 5th, helloo
string6, 6th, helloop
......


expected ouput
string1.str1.co.in,ZSER, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com,ABCD, 2nd, hello
string3,ZSE, 3rd, helloz
string4,ACD, 4th, hellox
string5,   ,5th, helloo
string6,   ,6th, helloop
.....
```

I have tried below but only works with exact match and prints, can we include couple of lines more to get expected one ?

```
awk '
 BEGIN{
 FS=OFS=","
 }
 FNR==NR{
 sub(/^ /,"")
 val=$1
 $1=""
 sub(/,/,"")
 sub(/,$/,"")
 a[val]=$0
 next
 }
 $1 in a{
 $1=$1 OFS a[$1]
 print $0
 }' file1.csv file2.csv

string1.str1.co.in,ZSER, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com,ABCD, 2nd, hello
```

If that makes difficult to get expected one .. plz suggest alternatives

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the first field on `.` and use only the first element as your associative array key. Given:

```
$ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==
string1.str1.co.in,ZSER
string2.str2.com,ABCD
string3.str.co.in,ZSE
string4.str2.com,ACD

==> file2 <==
string1.str1.co.in, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com, 2nd, hello
string3, 3rd, helloz
string4, 4th, hellox
string5, 5th, helloo
string5, 6th, helloop
```

then

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS=","}
    split($1,b,".") {key = b[1]}
    NR==FNR {a[key] = $2; next}
    (key in a) {$1 = $1 OFS a[key]}
    1
' file1 file2
string1.str1.co.in,ZSER, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com,ABCD, 2nd, hello
string3,ZSE, 3rd, helloz
string4,ACD, 4th, hellox
string5, 5th, helloo
string5, 6th, helloop
```

---

If you want to output a blank or other string in non matching cases you can change the last pattern-action pair from `(key in a) {$1 = $1 OFS a[key]}` to `{$1 = (key in a) ? $1 OFS a[key] : $1 OFS " "}`:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS=","}
    split($1,b,".") {key = b[1]}
    NR==FNR {a[key] = $2; next}
    {$1 = (key in a) ? $1 OFS a[key] : $1 OFS " "}
    1
' file1 file2
string1.str1.co.in,ZSER, [A], hello1, hello2
string2.str2.com,ABCD, 2nd, hello
string3,ZSE, 3rd, helloz
string4,ACD, 4th, hellox
string5, , 5th, helloo
string5, , 6th, helloop
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was typo in string5 row in expected output

Comment: @Sin15 please see updated answer

Comment: works .  is it possible for you to explain code ?  would get help me in gaining knowledge.